# not able to append row in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

****Not able to append row in new Data Frame**
Any affort would be appriciated**

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame()

z=pd.DataFrame()

x=input("input number")
x=int(x)
for i in range(x):
    y=input("enter srting")
    z=usda[usda.Description.str.contains("y")]

    new_df.append(z,ignore_index = True)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: What is `usda` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `new_df=new_df.append(z,ignore_index = True)`. Otherwise the new dataframe is not saved to the variable `new_df`.